# Unable to find $ml-yacc-lib.cm

Tags: ubuntu, sml, smlnj, ml

I try to installed a software written in *Standard ML of New Jersey (SML/NJ)*.

I don't know at all this language, but logically, I just install SML/NJ on my machine with the following command :

```
 sudo apt-get install smlnj
```

Then the author of the software explained that there is a CM file that need to be compile by using `CM.Make "sources.cm"`.

Here is the file `sources.cm`:

```
Group is 
    $/basis.cm
    $/smlnj-lib.cm
    $/pp-lib.cm
    int-binary-map.sml
    old-pp.sml

    nnf-sigs.sml
    options.sml
    statistics.sml
    basis.sml
    model-sigs.sml
    nnf.sml 
    model.sml
    sat.sml
    lexer.lex
    parser.sml
```

Unfortunately, when I call the function as I should, here is the error message :

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.76 [built: Tue Oct 22 14:04:11 2013]
- CM.make "sources.cm";
[autoloading]
[library $smlnj/cm/cm.cm is stable]
[library $smlnj/internal/cm-sig-lib.cm is stable]
[library $/pgraph.cm is stable]
[library $smlnj/internal/srcpath-lib.cm is stable]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/basis.cm is stable]
[autoloading done]
[scanning sources.cm]
[library $/pp-lib.cm is stable]
[attempting to load plugin $/lex-ext.cm]
[library $/lex-ext.cm is stable]
[library $smlnj/cm/tools.cm is stable]
[library $smlnj/internal/cm-lib.cm is stable]
[plugin $/lex-ext.cm loaded successfully]
[attempting to load plugin $/mllex-tool.cm]
[library $/mllex-tool.cm is stable]
[plugin $/mllex-tool.cm loaded successfully]
[library $SMLNJ-LIB/Util/smlnj-lib.cm is stable]
[library $SMLNJ-LIB/PP/pp-lib.cm is stable]
[library $html-lib.cm(=$SMLNJ-LIB/HTML)/html-lib.cm is stable]
[loading (sources.cm):int-binary-map.sml]
[loading (sources.cm):basis.sml]
[loading (sources.cm):nnf-sigs.sml]
[loading (sources.cm):statistics.sml]
[loading (sources.cm):options.sml]
[loading (sources.cm):old-pp.sml]
[loading (sources.cm):nnf.sml]
[loading (sources.cm):model-sigs.sml]
[loading (sources.cm):model.sml]
[loading (sources.cm):sat.sml]
[loading (sources.cm):lexer.lex.sml]
[loading (sources.cm):parser.sml]
Error: (stable) $html-lib.cm(=$SMLNJ-LIB/HTML)/html-lib.cm: unable to find $ml-yacc-lib.cm(=$SMLNJ-ML-YACC-LIB)/ml-yacc-lib.cm (/build/buildd/smlnj-110.76/sml.boot.x86-unix/SMLNJ-ML-YACC-LIB/ml-yacc-lib.cm)

uncaught exception Format
  raised at: ../cm/stable/stabilize.sml:257.15-257.21
             ../cm/stable/stabilize.sml:360.44
```

I don't know at all why there is this error, because except a fresh install and downloading a working source code, I've done nothing to crash it.

Thanks in advance for your help !
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it was just a missing library :

```
sudo apt-get install ml-yacc
```

fixed the problem.